# Would multiple touches at a fast speed and at the same time crash an android app?

Tags: java, android

For my android app, I want to make a simple game which would be either 2 player or 4 player. The game requires that all the players compete against each other in real time. If 2 players are present, 3 touches  at around the same time, if 4 players 6 touches at the same time. Would this much load crash the app?

Comment: Try to implement it and test it with various device. You will come to know how it will behave

Comment: The app will not crash but some older devices support less that 6 touches at the same time. You shouldn't have any issues with most modern devices.

Comment: Unless you have a bug in your touch handling, it will work.  However not all devices will support multitouch to that degree, especially non-tablets (as it isn't really convenient to touch a phone in that many distinct places).  But it won't crash, it just would register incorrect touch results.

Comment: Touching the screen this rapidly may cause the phone to fall out of your hands and onto the floor and could crack the screen or break the phone. Just saying :)

Comment: it won't crash an app itself. But your code may crash it, if you write it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

This wont crash the application. 
The touch information captured will be limited to the ability of the phones hardware just like keyboard strokes. On PC if it's under stress then the main machine can retrieve the stokes from registers after few times. I have an old phone that when in stress if typing shows nothing and after it loads its resources it retrieves touch information and shows the information on screen.

You didn't mention if its on the same phone screen, Then you must have specify the portion of screen for each individual but thats not a good idea as it's small. So the option is make it network based.
In that case just don't call a value before the value is present.
And you will be fine to experiment and be succeed.